# Is object free / freed on dealloc and / or release?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I recently took an objective-c test to see how I would do.

Turns out my score wasn't anywhere near as good as I hoped.  That means more studying.

During the test, I was asked this question:

How do you free an object?

A. [obj dealloc];
B. [obj release];
C. None of the above

My choice was A, and I don't know if it's correct.  The question is confusing:  Doesn't release call dealloc, therefore achieving the same result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. `release` decrements the object's reference count.

You don't call `dealloc` directly. Call `release` to decrement the reference count and let the runtime call `dealloc` when the reference count becomes zero.

Comment: Actually, release signals that you have relinquished your claim on ownership, no more, no less.  In practical terms, it usually means that the retain count of the object will be decremented, but not always e.g. inspect the retain count of a constant string before and after releasing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `release` does call `dealloc` but only *after* decrementing the reference count and only if the reference count went to zero.  The [NSObject class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/release) says that `release`:

```
"Decrements the receiver’s reference count."  

"The receiver is sent a dealloc message when its reference count reaches 0."
```

Comment: That doesn't mean that release chains a call to dealloc though. GC will send that dealloc on a reference check. Just wanted to clarify.

Comment: GC will never, ever, send `dealloc`.

Comment: How about a non GC environment?  That's what I was thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

I know an answer has already been accepted for this, but I can't resist adding my own thoughts.

The answer to the test question is technically C.  You don't free objects, the runtime frees them when it thinks they are no longer in use.

If you release an object in the reference counted environment, you are not freeing it, merely indicating that you are relinquishing any claim of ownership.  When nobody has an ownership claim, dealloc is called by the runtime and the object is freed.  Similarly, in the garbage collected environment, when you overwrite a reference, you are signalling that you are no longer interested in it. Once all references have gone, at some indeterminate time later, finalize is sent to the object and the object is freed.